# Ubuntu 12.04 Server Software RAID1 - Faulty Spare - Smart Output Passed - Confused

Tags: ubuntu, software-raid, mdadm, raid1, smartctl

I think I'm having an issue with one of the hard drives on my array and I'm just trying to troubleshoot what's happening.

Its saying Faulty Spare and then after reboot it just says removed:

```
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Wed Aug 15 15:28:06 2012
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 2920368960 (2785.08 GiB 2990.46 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 2920368960 (2785.08 GiB 2990.46 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Wed Aug 22 16:04:16 2012
          State : clean, degraded
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           Name : M2FileServer:0  (local to host M2FileServer)
           UUID : 778e5d32:1cd810e8:dfebb663:868d66e6
           Events : 45564

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
      0       8        2        0      active sync   /dev/sda2
      1       0        0        1      removed
```

Here's the parted l stuff so you can see my partitions

```
Model: ATA ST3000DM001-9YN1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      17.4kB  10.0GB  10.0GB  ext4               boot
 2      10.0GB  3001GB  2991GB  ext4               raid


Model: ATA ST3000DM001-9YN1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
1      17.4kB  10.0GB  10.0GB  linux-swap(v1)
2      10.0GB  3001GB  2991GB  ext4


Model: Linux Software RAID Array (md)
Disk /dev/md0: 2990GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  2990GB  2990GB  ext4
```

I ran the smartctl -a /dev/sdb2 and it said I passed, but compared to my working drive, the RAW_VALUE numbers were really high.

Here is the result:

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     ST3000DM001-9YN166
Serial Number:    W1F0NZZN
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 052948b97
Firmware Version: CC4B
User Capacity:    3,000,592,982,016 bytes [3.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   8
ATA Standard is:  ATA-8-ACS revision 4
Local Time is:    Wed Aug 22 15:52:02 2012 EDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                                        was completed without error.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (  584) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 255) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x3085) SCT Status supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   078   077   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       3096976
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   093   093   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       25
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   082   082   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       23920
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   100   253   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       994254
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       203
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       25
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       3
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       188
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       12885164036
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   006   006   000    Old_age   Always       -       94
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   058   053   045    Old_age   Always       -       42 (Min/Max 41/47)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       18
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       60
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   042   047   000    Old_age   Always       -       42 (0 21 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   074   025   000    Old_age   Always       -       4344
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   074   025   000    Old_age   Offline      -       4344
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       159678294130889
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       462985523872
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1565986232

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]


SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Thanks for your help in advance! 
Jess

Answer (score 0):

actually it seems like you have not successfully undergone any selftest, yet:

```
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]
```

try running smartctl -t long /dev/sdb.

Answer (score 0):

```
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   082   082   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       23920
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       3
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       188
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       12885164036
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   074   025   000    Old_age   Always       -       4344
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   074   025   000    Old_age   Offline      -       4344
```

The drive's failing, but it's not sufficiently failed to trigger a "SMART failure", since all of the error-related numbers are above their failure thresholds.  The most likely cause of the RAID failure event is an uncorrectable read error (SMART attribute 187).